How to calculate efficiency of this half wave rectifier circuit in LTspice?

I have a project to simulate fast-charging power supply, and I want to find the efficiency the power at the output is 48w but at the ac supply (311.13 peak V) and (i peak 3.87 A).  I don't know how to find the power or find the power factor. I know the efficiency will be poor, but I want exact number.

If you need a number which is as close as possible to an exact one, you will need a good physical model for the transformer, to account for its losses.

@devnull I know it doesn’t need to be the same of the real thing my question is I don’t know how to calculate the power consumed by the AC source so that i can find the efficiency

After a transient simulation, if you hold down the Alt key and hover the cursor over the component or source, it will give a thermometer cursor icon.
Then a left-click will plot the instantaneous power.
To get the average power, Ctrl left-click that trace's title in the plot.

Input power can be easily calculated using LTSpice; it's just the average of v(Vs) x i(L1). When plotted in LTSpice, the graph will settle down to a constant value (after many cycles of AC) and that constant value is the average input power.
You can do exactly the same for power into the 3 Ω load; label the output node (say Vo) and take the average of v(Vo) x i(R_load).
Now you have average input power as a constant value and average output power as a constant value (once the initial conditions have settled down). The ratio is the power efficiency.
No need for power factor at all; it does not help one little bit.
